# Reorganizing 3 Columns of Data in Excel

Tags: excel

I would like to organize a very large data set, (1800 companies, monthly dates between 2002 and 2017)so that dates(without duplicates) are in the first column, company name is in the first row, and the cusip numbers are filled in the cells between. I am trying to organize data on historical cusip codes. A sample of my data is shown below. Right now the data is organized in 3 columns titled "date", "Company name" and "Cusip". Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

```
1/31/02 AETNA INC NEW   00817Y10

1/31/02 ALIGN TECHNOLOGY INC    1625510

1/31/02 ALLIANCE DATA SYSTEMS CORP  1858110

1/31/02 ADVISORY BOARD CO   00762W10

1/31/02 ACUITY BRANDS INC   00508Y10

1/31/02 ADVANCE AUTO PARTS INC  00751Y10

1/31/02 INVERNESS MED INNOVATIONS INC   01449J10

2/28/02 AKORN INC   972810

2/28/02 ADVANCED MAGNETICS INC  00163U10
```

Comment: If you don't want duplicates in your sorting, you need to remove duplicates before you apply the sort.

Comment: The only thing I have done at this point is put the dates in chronological order. My goal is to have one of each date in the first column and have one of each company in the top row. The cells would be filled in with the matching cusip code.

Comment: Use `Power Pivot` or `Data --> Get & Transform` to `Pivot` on the Company name but use the option  `Don't aggregate`.  For Values use the Cusip Number.